# How to delete the summary table in minicart page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, order-totals

I want to remove the summary from this page [image]

and how to remove shipping method  and the part of price and product from this page  [image]
[image]

Comment: Do you want to remove whole section from right side? And what about the 2nd and 3rd image? Please explain.

Comment: yes i want to eliminate the whole section

Answer (score 0):

You try below layout update to remove whole "summary" block from the cart page

**Case 1 : Using Theme**

I assume you are using a custom Theme name "Company_mytheme".

create **checkout_cart_index.xml** under
**app/design/frontend/Company/mytheme/Magento_Checkout/layout/**

File : **checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="cart.summary" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

**Case 2 : Using custom extenstion**

I assume you are using a custom extenstion names "Company_Module"

Create create **checkout_cart_index.xml** under
***/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/layout***

File : **checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="cart.summary" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

**Note** : Please flush magento cache.